# MacLaurin powerseries and interval of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Given the function $f(x) = 5/(6*x^2-x-1)$,
(a) Expand into MacLaurin powerseries the function $f$ up to order $3$.
(b) Find the interval of convergence of it.

(a) I will use the type of $$\frac{1}{0!}f(0) + \frac{1}{1!}f^{(1)}(0)x + \frac{1}{2!}f^{(2)}(0)x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}f^{(3)}(0)x^3 = -5+5x-35x^2+65x^3$$

(b) I will test the $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_{(n+1)}/a_{n}| = 1$. Now, given the number "1", I don't know how to continue. Can someone give me some tips?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use **partial fractions** to put $5/(6x^2-x-1)$ in nice form. Note that the denominator factors as $(3x+1)(2x-1)$. So you will be looking for an expression of shape $\frac{A}{2x-1}+\frac{B}{3x+1}$.

Note that for example the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+2x}$ is easy, since $\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+\cdots$.

You can then combine the two expansions to get an explicit formula for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series expansion of your original function.

You can do a ratio test on these, not too messy.

But there is an easier way. One of the two component series has radius of convergence $1/2$, the other $1/3$. The radius of convergence of the combination is th radius of convergence of the bad one, which is $1/3$,

**Remark:** Partial fractions are good for other things than integration!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I haven't understood this: For the first question, is my way wrong or do I have to use partial fractions necessarily?

Comment: For (a), all you need to do is to compute the function value at $0$ and a couple of derivatives at $0$. Fairly simple. Would not be much fun if you needed the $17$-th derivative of your function! For radius of convergence, you need some control over all derivatives, so I don't see how you can avoid the partial fractions approach. I am lying, there is a fancy theorem that will tell you the answer, but for your present knowledge I am not really lying.